# Way to enforce a specific set of children in MySQL one-to-many?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, one-to-many, database-trigger

I have some tables like the following that describe configurations of skus, where a configuration has a specific set of properties depending on what sku family it is describing.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS skuConfig (
   id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   configId BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS config (
   id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   skuFamily VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS configProperty (
   id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   configId BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   propName VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
   propValue VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

I would like to enforce that when a new config is created, if it describes a skuFamily 'X', then it must be referenced by 3 configProperty records with propNames 'a', 'b', and 'c'. If a config is created describing skuFamily 'Y', it must be referenced by 2 configProperty records with propNames 'e' and 'f'.

Is there a way to do this using the provided 3 tables, or would this be something better handled with a dedicated table for each config type that matches one skuFamily? For example something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS skuConfig (
   id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   configId BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   skuFamily VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS skuFamilyXConfig (
   id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   a VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
   b VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
   c VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS skuFamilyYConfig (
   id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   d VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
   e VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Where the configId field in skuConfig table will refer to an id in one of the skuFamilyConfig tables.

Thanks in advance for any help with this, I am quite new to SQL but am willing to investigate using triggers or changing the schema, whatever makes more sense for maintaining these restrictions.

Comment: I feel that perhaps you have bad design here.  The usual thing would be to add foreign key constraints the two config family tables, requiring that they point to a SKU in `skuConfig` which actually exists.  But the insert order would be first to SKU, then to Config, not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Tim Biegeleisen that makes much more sense